# Creating a video from an audio file in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, video

I have recorded an audio file, and would like to upload it to Youtube. But Youtube requires me to convert it firstly to video. So how do you do that in Ubuntu? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if there are some online websites that can do this?

Comment: This isn't the place to ask for web services.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the Open Shot Video Editor. First install it:

```
sudo apt-get install openshot
```

Since you only have music you will need a picture to use as the "video" part of the video. Once you have decided on a photo, open Open Shot and import your files.

[image]

Now drag your files into the timeline below, picture on top and music below.

[image]

You'll notice that the music is much longer than the picture, so we'll need to lengthen the time the picture is on the screen. Zoom out so you can see the entire length of the music.

[image]

Now select the resize tool and increase the length of the picture so that it matches the length of the music.

[image]

When you're done you will need to export the video. Click the "Export" button, fill out the dialog the way you want and click "Export".

[image]

You can now upload your video to Youtube.

Comment: Thanks. how did you draw those boxes and arrows?

Comment: @T... I use a program called [Shutter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter/).

Comment: Do you know if there are some online websites that can do this? Even simply by adding no image or a single image for the new video.

Comment: @T... You might be able to do it in the YouTube video editor..

Comment: @Seth Beautiful. But I couldn't see the two boxes yellow in my cases, both came on track 2(adjacent), not separate on track 1. Is there way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Avidemux.  Avidemux allows you to create a video file from an audio file.

To install just do it from [Ubuntu Apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=Avidemux&op=), or see their [website](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) to download.  for how to see [Avidemux wiki documentation](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with ffmpeg much easily. See this thread

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -y -i black_still_image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -c:a copy -r 1 -vcodec libx264 -shortest video_out.avi
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381086/convert-mp3-video-with-static-image-ffmpeg-libav-bash